# How to make submenu items appear while parents stay the same in fullscreen overlay menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
.imglogo {
  padding: 5% 15% 5% 10%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72);
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  box-shadow: -6px -4px 18px 7px #7a77a2;
  background: center center no-repeat:
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #7a77a2;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.submenu1 {
  font-family: gotham-gds;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu2 {
  font-family: gotham-gds;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu3 {
  font-family: gotham-gds;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu4 {
  font-family: gotham-gds;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu5 {
  font-family: gotham-gds;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.small {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.overlay-content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.encima li a {
  display: block;
}

.encima li ul {
  position: absolute;
}

.encima li:hover ul,
.encima li:focus ul {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.encima li ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.encima:hover .submenu1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -7% 0% 0 20%;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.encima:hover .submenu2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -10% 0% 0 30%;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.encima:hover .submenu3 {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -10% 0% 0 30%;
  text-align: left;
}

.encima:hover .submenu4 {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -10% 0% 0 25%;
  text-align: left;
}

.encima:hover .submenu5 {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -10% 0% 0 20%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">

      <ul>
        <div class="encima">
          <li> <a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <ul class="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="encima">
          <li> <a href="#">link2</a></li>
          <ul class="submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="encima">
          <li> <a href="#">Link3</a></li>
          <ul class="submenu3">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="encima">

          <li> <a href="#">Link4</a></li>
          <ul class="submenu4">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="encima">
          <li> <a href="#">link5</a></li>
          <ul class="submenu5">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

  <span style="font-size:28px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <a href="#">open menu</a>
    </div>
  </span>

</body>
```

Thanks for the help in advance! I would like child appearing at right and parents not moving, but I don´t know where I missed positioning attributes.

I am trying to build a vertical fullscreen overlay menu(triggered from a logo image), where parent items have submenu items, but I would like them to display just at the right of the "parents block". Problem is that when child elements display on hover, the next parents move downwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the property `position: absolute` to your "submenu":

```
.encima ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly!! I think I tried so many different combinations that I couldn´t see the obvious answer. Thanks a lot and best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake in HTML Structure use submenu `ul` inside of `li` and change one css from

```
.encima li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
.imglogo{
        padding: 5% 15% 5% 10%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.72);
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
   box-shadow: -6px -4px 18px 7px #7a77a2;
   background: center center no-repeat:
    
}
.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.99);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
 }

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #7a77a2;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
.submenu1{
    font-family: gotham-gds;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    }
.submenu2{
    font-family: gotham-gds;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    }
.submenu3{
    font-family: gotham-gds;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    }
.submenu4{
    font-family: gotham-gds;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    }
.submenu5{
    font-family: gotham-gds;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    }
.small{
    font-size:16px !important;
}
 .overlay-content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
 }
 .encima li a {
    display:block;
 }
 .encima li ul{
    position: absolute;
 }

 .encima li:hover ul, .encima li:focus ul{
    width:100%;
    z-index: 5;
 }
 .encima li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    
 }
 .encima:hover .submenu1{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: -7% 0% 0 20%;
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
 }    
 .encima:hover .submenu2{
    display:inline-block;
     margin: -10% 0% 0 30%;
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    
   }
   .encima:hover .submenu3{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
     margin: -10% 0% 0 30%;
    text-align: left;
   }
    .encima:hover .submenu4{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -10% 0% 0 25%;
    text-align: left;
    }
    .encima:hover .submenu5{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: slide-down .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-down .5s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -10% 0% 0 20%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content"> 
    <ul>
        <div class="encima"> 
            <li> <a href="#">Link1</a>
                <ul class="submenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="encima"> 
            <li> <a href="#">Link2</a>
                <ul class="submenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div><div class="encima"> 
            <li> <a href="#">Link3</a>
                <ul class="submenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div><div class="encima"> 
            <li> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                <ul class="submenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div><div class="encima"> 
            <li> <a href="#">Link5</a>
                <ul class="submenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>     
  </div>
</div>

<span style="font-size:28px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" >
        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <a href="#">open menu</a>
        </div>
</span>
```

Comment: That´s true!! So grateful! I will change it according to your indications. Best regards :)